# Change the font based on language CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, tumblr

Please check this code; I am trying to change the font and text-align based on language :

The style

```
<style> 
  .quotebod { 
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
    line-height: 22px; 
    font-size: 20px; 
  }

  :lang(ar) { 
    text-align:right; 
    font-family:'Droid Arabic Kufi'; 
  }

  .quotebod:lang(ar) { 
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
    line-height: 30px; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    text-align:right; 
    font-family:'Droid Arabic Kufi'; 
  }</style>

<body><p class="quotebod">{Quote}</p></body>
```

**{Quote}: a tumblr variable but it's text too **

Comment: Where exactly `lang` attribute is defined? Is it applied to the whole text, or just some fragments?

Comment: Should work fine, if language is defined in `<html lang="ar">` or something like this. One thing, though; it's not necessary to set-up `text-align: right` for RTL languages, it's usually done by browser  itself.

Comment: @raina77ow No, This is not the whole code, It is large code But Must I define lang attribute ? where ( <html>,<head>, <style> or <body>? And how ?

Comment: The problem is I have texts in arabic and english in the same page, The code works for only one language and I do not know why; I mean the code works in arabic text and english text with the same action ( english text aligned right), And I do not want that.

Comment: And I want to let you know that thee {Quote} is changed; sometimes it is arabic and sometimes it is english. So I Want to check if the lang is arabic then change the font and text align if not then keep it as body css !! That's it !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite fine to have texts in different languages in the same page. Usually in this case it's easy to determine the 'main' language of the HTML; that language should be used in `lang` attribute of `<html>` element. Next, you add `lang` for each element containing text written in different language.

In case when one language is LTR, and other is RTL, it's also good to specify `dir` attribute as well, following the same approach. For example:

```
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>«فى هذا الكتاب مقارنة بين تعاليم الإسلام كما وصلت إلينا، وبين أصدق ما وصلت إليه حضارة الغرب فى أدب النفس والسلوك فى محاولة للكشف عن روعة التقارب وصدق التطابق»</p>
    <p lang="en" dir="ltr"> These are some of the words of the author, which cross them about the reason for writing this unique work</p> 
    <p>.. هذه بعض كلمات المؤلف التى عبر بها عن سبب كتابته لهذا العمل الفريد، خاصة بعد قراءته لكتاب «دع القلق وابدأ الحياة» لديل كارنيجى وقد اعتمد فى هذا العمل على جانبين رئيسين.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can easily adjust styling of each separate element by using `:lang` selector. Take note that once set up on `html`, it'll be inherited by all the elements - unless overwritten directly.

So in the document above, `p:lang(ar)` selector will be applied both the first and the third paragraphs - but not to the second one.

Now to the question. Let's say we have an element that might contain text in either Arabic or English. You might've guessed already that it's not enough just to change the text itself - you'd also adjust accordingly `lang` attribute of that element. For example:

```
// here goes the code that receives the quotation
<p class="quotebod" lang="{Quote.lang}" dir="{Quote.dir}">{Quote}</p>
```

The hard part would be detecting the language by the quote. I suppose that's easy to do at the source, but you can do it the client-side as well by analyzing the contents of `Quote` - if they contain symbols from the Arabic alphabet, they're hardly in English - and vice versa.

For example, let's say we have an HTML containing different types of text in a shallow structure - each paragraph contains a block of text in either Arabic or English. Here's how we can assign `lang` and `dir` attributes accordingly:

```
var arabicPatt = /[\u0600-\u06ff]/;
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p'), function(p) {
  var lang, dir;
  if (arabicPatt.test(p.textContent)) {
    lang = 'ar'; dir = 'rtl';
  }
  else {
    lang = 'en'; dir = 'ltr';
  }
  p.setAttribute('lang', lang);
  p.setAttribute('dir', dir);
});
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/xfc2vwp5/). Note that I didn't set up `text-align: right` in CSS - it was done by the browser once the elements received corresponding `dir` value.

Comment: Thank you,sir: But where to add the Javascript code? I add it before <style> and no effects :( ! And do I have to change anything in the Javascript code?

Comment: I add it everywhere and no effects :( ! 
This is the code in {Quote} 
`<a href="{PermaLink}" > <blockquote><p class="quotebod"        lang="{Quote.lang}" dir="{Quote.dir}">{Quote}</p></blockquote></a>`

Comment: I am sure this javascript does not work with tumblr variables, I do not know.

Comment: What do you mean by " // setting up a character class `[\u0600-\u06ff]` manually, 
    // otherwise it won't be a proper range " ?