# Enable and disable css file dynamically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am very new to javascript. I am creating a multilingual website. It contains rtl and ltr languages. I have two css for those to languages. When user change his language I want to load respective css file. Is it possible in this way ? If not suggest any alternative way.

Comment: why do you want to do this? are you unable to edit the html to remove the files you don't want?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to change css file dynamically.

Comment: @madhankumar you cannot do that. But you can always change the CSS individual properties dynamically

Comment: what do you mean by change css file? you want to change things inside the file or you want to swap it with another css file altogether?

Comment: You can't disable css files with javascript. The proper way of doing it would be to add/remove css classes with javascript and/or use css media queries to display certain rules when you want to. Google CSS Media Queries and Changing CSS Class with javascript/jquery.

Comment: @Cruiser plz read my question again. Suggest any solution.

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827756/change-the-font-based-on-language-css

Comment: otherwise, SO is a place for getting help with stuck code, not a "how to"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is posible enable and disable css stylesheet with javascript. A example: http://plnkr.co/0exLXB

```
function del_style() {
    document.getElementById("styles").disabled=true;
}

function add_style() {
    document.getElementById("styles").disabled=false;
}
```

I think you could adapt the code for your site