# How to enable disabled CSS using radio button and JavaScript for changing full website colors

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Let us suppose I have two CSS files. Both are linked with my index.html. Let us suppose that one of these CSS files contains all themes in red and another one in blue. So that if we enable the first one, we get red color in our website and if enable the second one, then we get blue color.

For example I used this:

**Default enabled**

`link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="red.css"`

**Default disabled**

`link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blue.css" disabled`

These both links are present in same page.

Now please tell me the solution how I can enable the second one and disable the first one using radio button in main page?
So that a user can choose according to his preference.

I hope you understand.

Comment: Your question already has an answer. See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37416531/4508593. To enable/disable a CSS stylesheet, you can set the disabled property of the CSS file to true/false. You can give each CSS link an id attribute and then refer to it using the id. For example: `document.getElementById("stylesheet_id").disabled=false;` will disable the stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this is javascript or jQuery inside radio button onClick function. You need to add/remove disabled attribute from respective link element.

**jQuery Code:**

```
$('link[name="red_style_sheet"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
$('link[name="blue_style_sheet"]').removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
document.getElementsByName("red_style_sheet").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
document.getElementsByName("blue_style_sheet").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

You don't need to refresh page. It should work automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it dynamically through JavaScript. Here’s how you would add a style sheet after the page has already loaded:

```
var link =  document.createElement("link")
link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
link.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
link.setAttribute("href", "color.css");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```

Comment: You would remove the old one in the same block of code. For example: $(“link[href=‘color-to-remove.css’]”).remove();